# followUser function doesn't add id into both followers and followings array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, jwt

verifyToken.js

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) =\> { try { const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(" ")\[1\]; const isCustomAuth = token?.length \< 500;

let decodedData;

if (token && isCustomAuth) {   decodedData = jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_KEY);

req.user = decodedData?.id; else { decodedData = jwt.decode(token);

req.user = decodedData?.sub;

next(); catch (error) { console.log(error); } }
```

User.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, max: 50, }, username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, max: 20, }, fullname: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, max: 50, }, password: { type: String, required: true, min: 6, }, followings: { type: Array, default: \[\], }, followers: { type: Array, default: \[\], }, profilePicture: { type: String, default: "", }, coverPicture: { type: String, default: "", }, location: { type: String, max: 30, }, website: { type: String, default: "", max: 100, }, dateOfBirth: { type: String, required: true, match: /^\\d{2}\[/-\]\\d{2}\[/-\]\\d{4}$/, // Match format "MM-DD-YYYY" }, }, timestamps: true } );

export default mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);
```

userRoutes.js

```
import express from 'express'; import { verifyToken } from '../middleware/verifyToken.js'; import { update, deleteUser, getUser, friendsList, followUsers, unfollowUsers } from '../controllers/User.js';

const router = express.Router();

Update the User router.put('/:id', verifyToken, update);

Delete the User router.delete('/:id', verifyToken, deleteUser);

Get a user router.get('/find/:id', getUser);

Friends List router.get('friends/:userId', friendsList);

Follow a User router.put('/follow/:id', verifyToken, followUsers);

Unfollow a User router.put('/unfollow/:id', verifyToken, unfollowUsers);

export default router;
```

controllers/User.js

```
export const followUsers = async (req, res, next) =\> { if (req.params.id !== req.user?.id) { try { const user = await User.findById(req.params.id); const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user?.id);

if (!user.followers.includes(req.user?.id)) { await user.updateOne({ $push: { followers: req.user?.id }, });

await currentUser?.updateOne({ $push: { followings: req.params.id }, });

res.status(200).json("User has been followed"); else { return next(createError(403, "You already follow yourself")); } catch (error) { console.error(error); next(error); } else { return next(createError(403, "You can't follow only your account!")); } };

export const unfollowUsers = async (req, res, next) =\> { if (req.params?.id !== req.user?.id) { try { const user = await User.findById(req.params.id); const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user.id);

if (user.followers.includes(req.user?.id)) { await user.updateOne({ $pull: { follower: req.user?.id }}); await currentUser.updateOne({ $pull: { following: req.params.id }}); res.status(200).json("user has been unfollowed"); } else { return next(createError(403, "You already unfollow this user")); } catch (error) { next(error); } } else { return next(createError(403, "You can't follow only your account!")); } };
```

When I authenticate and receive my token, I'm trying to follow the other user by adding his id into my following array and his/her followers array/ But it didn't request and response. How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Is `=\>` even a thing in JavaScript? Why is everything so hard to read

Comment: Can you please format the code in a readable way?